# SQL Azure stored procedure to SELECT rows that may be overriden

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a SQL Azure table which contains info for components and parts. I need to write a stored procedure that returns a correct list of parts for a given component. However, it is complicated by the fact that certain rows need to be "overriden".

My table looks like:

```
ComponentID | Position | PartID | Area    | City   |
------------+----------+--------+---------+--------+
3           | 1        | F      | Europe  | None   |
3           | 1        | G      | England | None   |
3           | 1        | S      | England | London |
3           | 2        | H      | Europe  | None   |
3           | 2        | I      | England | None   |
3           | 3        | Q      | Europe  | None   |
```

The "override" here is that if you are more specific about a location, you should retrieve the details for the most specific part in position X that you can find. i.e. base versions may be available but others may take precedence. I then need to ignore everything apart from the most specific version.

The stored procedure I have written is not working. The sproc should take a componentID, an area and a city and return the appropriate components in order of their position. So, the following examples should hold:

> ```
> Input: 3, Europe, None:
>
> 1 F
> 2 H
> 3 Q
>
> Input: 3, England, None:
>
> 1 G
> 2 I
> 3 Q
>
> Input: 3, England, London: 
>
> 1 S
> 2 I
> 3 Q
> ```

I don't have my failed sproc code to hand, but can attach it in a few hours...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to reuse the result, I would create a function instead of a stored procedure. If you really wanted an SP, you can use the query within the function I create below.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2789f/2/0)

**Schema Setup**:

```
create table tbl (
ComponentID int, Position int, PartID char(1), Area sysname   , City sysname );
insert into tbl select
3           , 1        , 'F'      , 'Europe'  , 'None'   union all select
3           , 1        , 'G'      , 'England' , 'None'   union all select
3           , 1        , 'S'      , 'England' , 'London' union all select
3           , 2        , 'H'      , 'Europe'  , 'None'   union all select
3           , 2        , 'I'      , 'England' , 'None'   union all select
3           , 3        , 'Q'      , 'Europe'  , 'None';

create function dbo.getComponents(
  @ComponentID int,
  @Area sysname,
  @City sysname)
returns table as return
with ranked as (
  select Position, PartID, rownum = row_number() over
    (partition by Position order by
     case when @Area=Area and @City=City then 1
          when @Area=Area then 2
          else 3 end)
    from tbl
)
select Position, PartID
from ranked
where rownum=1
GO
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from dbo.getComponents(3, 'Europe', 'None') order by PartID
```

**Results**:

```
| POSITION | PARTID |
---------------------
|        1 |      F |
|        2 |      H |
|        3 |      Q |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select * from dbo.getComponents(3, 'England', 'None') order by PartID
```

**Results**:

```
| POSITION | PARTID |
---------------------
|        1 |      G |
|        2 |      I |
|        3 |      Q |
```

**Query 3**:

```
select * from dbo.getComponents(3, 'England', 'London') order by PartID
```

**Results**:

```
| POSITION | PARTID |
---------------------
|        2 |      I |
|        3 |      Q |
|        1 |      S |
```

Comment: Awesome, it works a treat. One correction... I needed to add a clause  after "from tbl" - "where ComponentID = @ComponentID". Otherwise spot on. Thanks for your help!